# Is it better practice to include "flint.h" or "flint/flint.h"

Tags: c++, c, header-files, include-path, subdirectory

The [Flint](http://flintlib.org/) library put all headers into `$PREFIX/include/flint/`. The [Arb](http://fredrikj.net/arb/) library then includes Flint headers. Which of these two is a better practice for Arb to include them:

1. `#include "flint.h"`
2. `#include "flint/flint.h"`

Pros/cons:

If Arb and Flint are installed in `/usr/include` (e.g. in Debian), then with 2., the user doesn't have to do anything, but with 1., the user needs to use `-I/usr/include/flint`.

So the advantage of 2. is that users who use the Arb library only need to specify include paths (`-I`) to the `$PREFIX/include` for all libraries needed. With 1., one has to include the path `$PREFIX/include/flint`, so it seems like more work.

Comment: I personally prefer the 2. form.

Comment: What if somebody else has also a flint.h in a different project and you need to use that file too? You will need to use "flint/.." form. So stick with that from the beginning.

Comment: Why should this question be closed as opinion based? There is a convincing technical argument why the the second form should be preferred.

Comment: Exactly, both answers below (@pmr, @piokuc) show that 2. is the way to go. Thank you both for answering!

Comment: Use what the documentation suggests.  The Flint 2.4.4 documentation contains a reference to `#include "flint.h"`; follow that unless you're sure you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

Always use the path relative to `/usr/include`. This way your code will build out of the box on most UNIX systems and you avoid name collisions (think header `util.h`).

As soon as your projects needs to be ported to less developer friendly platforms (mostly Windows) your build system will need to determine the location of your dependencies and set the appropriate compiler switches.

Comment: Thanks! So 2. is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Developers of libraries tend to put a class A into a header file A.h. In case you use two libraries which happen to have classes with the same name, it may happen that you include a header from a wrong library, depending on the order of include directories passed via -I. It does happen sometimes. The C++ namespace mechanism does not help here. So doing:

```
#include "x/A.h"
```

instead of just

```
#include "A.h"
```

may help you to avoid these kind of name collisions and ensure A.h from the x library is included, and not, for example, from the y library.